# Etymology of using of “to favor” to mean “to resemble”, “to take after”

Tags: etymology, dialects, colloquialisms, transatlantic-differences, register

I know that in at least some North American dialects,
*favor* as a verb can be used colloquially to
indicate that two people share a similar physical
appearance, especially when the two look so similar
that the physical appearance of one makes you think
of the other.

So I guess you could use it in place of something like  *takes after*, *looks like*, *reminds me of*, *bears a (striking) resemblance to*,or simply *resembles*.

For example:

- That child favors her father.
- I don’t see how you could possibly think she favors her mother.

Does anyone know the etymology of this particular use of *favor*?

Comment: [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/favor) gives *Middle English from Old French from Latin from favēre to be favorable* (which is nicely tautological).

Comment: In case this helps with anyone's answer, this is OED definition 8, earliest attestation 1609.

Comment: As a Brit speaker I have never heard of this. I would always say 'resembles'.

Comment: @NigelJ I bet it will be gone in a few generations. This is something my grandparents would say but I wouldn’t.

Comment: It just means the kid looks *like the father*.

Answer (score 7):

As commenters have indicated, this use of **favor** has a long history.  It is indeed Middle English (**favour**) with a French parallel (**faveur**) - all according to the OED.

The transitive verb meaning

> to resemble in face or features; rarely, to resemble generally have the look of...

can be traced to Ben Jonson in 1609, and a parade of others running into the 19th century (thanks and a hat-tip to @RaceYouAnytime).

A possibly earlier noun usage

> appearance, aspect, look

is cited as early as 1450 by the OED. Whether or not this relates to "favour" as a ribbon or badge to be worn in competition, it seems to cement this "representative" idea of favor/favour firmly in the history of the language.  Interestingly, these definitions are labeled "archaic" or "dialect" by OED.  Like many popular expressions, this one must have migrated to the American colonies, where it became entrenched or isolated depending on regional populations.

The rest lies somewhere between history and mystery.

Comment: You could also say someone/something "tends towards" or "leans toward" whatever they resemble more, whether it's an individual or a characteristic like being tall/thin/pretty. So that kind of idea might influence the meaning.

Comment: @StuartF Interestingly compared with the OED, Merriam-Webster does **not** label this sense in any way, let alone as  regional or colloquial or archaic, [in American English](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/favor#dictionary-entry-2). Interestingly, and in contrast to MW, AHD says that this sense is [*Chiefly Southern US*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=favor). Cambridge leaves it unlabelled in the US but [marks it as “old-fashioned” in the UK](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/favour?q=favour_1); I guess Ben Jonson’s long gone. :)